# Need help implementing this PHP library in my Project

Tags: php

For a class assignment I have to build a calculator that uses a PHP backend logic to calculate the user input. I came across this library on GitHub that is a perfect fit for my requirement;

https://github.com/chriskonnertz/string-calc

From what I understand I can simply send an user input string (e.g. '64*5') from HTML to the calculate() function in StringCalc.php to evaluate a result that I can display back to HTML.

My problem however is I am unable to setup a index.php file that can create an StringCalc oject so that I can use it's function calculate() for user input that I may fetch using $_POST. (I have attached a screenshot of what I am writing in index.php).
[index.php file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Z8Vd.jpg)

I created an empty directory and then used composer as stated in README of this repo.

composer require chriskonnertz/string-calc

In the base folder I created an index.php file (I have attached a screenshot for reference) and included StringCalc.php using its relative path.

But I keep getting this error:

"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "ChrisKonnertz\StringCalc\Container\ServiceProviderRegistry" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\StringCalc\vendor\chriskonnertz\string-calc\src\ChrisKonnertz\StringCalc\StringCalc.php:68 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\StringCalc\index.php(5): ChrisKonnertz\StringCalc\StringCalc->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\StringCalc\vendor\chriskonnertz\string-calc\src\ChrisKonnertz\StringCalc\StringCalc.php on line 68"[empty folder pulled code using composer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSD1Y.jpg)
[Error as displayed in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biXQe.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to require "vendor/autoload.php" packages namespaces will be available for you to use anywhere.
You need to delete the "include" code and add '/vendor/...' to head index.php

```
require '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

or relative path to this directory